# git fetch not working after local deletion of a branch

Tags: git

So, it's worth a little history on this to give a context.

I had done a rebase/reset on my local branch, and pushed it to `origin`.

Now, it was time to pull changes down to the testing server:

```
git pull (or git pull --force, etc)
```

did not work, giving me this message(s);

```
forge@myrepository:~/test.myserver.com$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From github.com:ykgw/myrepository
+ 6ef07eb...9883f8a feature/558-add-preview-button -> origin/feature/558-add-preview-button  (forced update)
Auto-merging app/api/NodesController.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/api/NodesController.php
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

forge@myrepository:~/test.myserver.com$ git checkout master
app/api/NodesController.php: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
forge@myrepository:~/test.myserver.com$ git pull --force
U   app/api/NodesController.php
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
                                                                     as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

I was finally able to switch to master and delete the branch in question, but then `git fetch` did not show the branch I wanted to pull down clean.  What do I do to make the testing server re-recognize it in the repo?

Comment: Look at that file for conflicts, resolve them and commit. Then you can pull again

Comment: The instructions are right at the bottom. `Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files. Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'`. But it sounds like you did something after that and aren't showing it.

Answer (score 0):

Git only speaks to the remote server when you tell it to. As a result, it keeps a copy of the remote repository in "remote tracking branches". `origin/master` is a remote tracking branch, it's a copy of `master` from the remote `origin`.

`master` is a local branch, possibly a branch of `origin/master`.

`git fetch` does not touch local branches, it updates the remote tracking branches. Basically it updates your view of the remote. So a `git fetch` will update `origin/master` but it will not merge those updates into `master`, nor will it create `master`.

You need to `git pull` to also update your local branches. `git pull origin master` is basically a `git fetch origin` + `git merge origin/master`.

Comment: More like `git fetch origin master` + `git merge FETCH_HEAD`. Only the to-be merged branch is fetched.